# Batch or Script to Reset Specific Profiles

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to 'reset' user's profiles with a script.

All I need to do is collect a string from user input. Take the first letter from the string.

**eg:** **Auser01**

Go to a specific server folder that the profile is on:

**EG: A users are in folder on Server1, B users are in Server2.**

Finally take administrator ownership of that folder and files and rename it.

**EG: Auser01_old**

I'm afraid I don't really know where to start apart from setting the string! Hope someone can guide me to writing this and what language. A batch script is where I have started.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far ? EG: the batch script you have started

Comment: I've literally got this:

@echo off
set /p username= Enter the username :

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, `ICACLS` is used to take ownership of folder, `REN` is used to rename folder, so the user enters a letter (A or B) then the `if` statement goes the command needed (ServerA or ServerB) the `icacls` and `ren` command run and the script ends. if you need a further explanation let me know.
Change `username_or_usergroup` to the user you want to take ownership

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
:User_input 
Set/p "input=Username>"
set letter=%input:~0,1%


:Check_server
If "%Letter%" == "a" (
    Goto ServerA
    )   

if "%Letter%" == "b" (
    Goto ServerB
    )   
Goto END

:ServerA
icacls \\ServerA\%input% /grant username_or_usergroup:F /t /q
Ren \\ServerA\%input% \\ServerA\%input%_old
Goto END

:ServerB
icacls \\ServerB\%input% /grant username_or_usergroup:F /t /q
Ren \\ServerB\%input% \\ServerB\%input%_old
Goto END

:END
```

This is the output i got when testing
[image]

Comment: This is genius thanks! I'm now trying it out and customising it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I sort of see what it's trying to do. 
I need to keep my first part of the script on the top don't I? (ie: set/p username= Enter the username:)
I am not sure if I explained correctly. I want to extract the first letter from the %username%. If the first letter is A for example, go to server 1 etc. Then find the folder in that server.

So I expect I only need one string to be captured. Confusing myself now!

Comment: no all the user has to enter is the letter A or B if you look at `Set Folder=%letter%%username%` `%username%` is a windows var that is equal to the current user so if User01 is logged in `%username%` will be equal to User01 So `%folder%` will equal AUser01 if the user types A and BUser01 if the user types B

Comment: I still don't think I've made sense! 
The user isn't logged on, they are logged off! 
The client comes to the office, says their profile is corrupted. We then enter their username, the script takes the first letter and recognises which folder to go to from the first letter. Finds the folder and grants admin permissions/owner and renames.
Each user has a specific letter at the start of their username always, the next 3 letters are the first 3 of their surname and then the last 2 will be a number. (auser01, auser02, auser 03 etc or of course buser01 buser02 on another server.)

Comment: _If there is an easier to understand way of doing this, for example VBS perhaps that would be easier to code?_

Comment: so are all the username the same length ?

Comment: Try it now `set letter=%input:~0,-5%`  should extract the first letter if the username is 5 or 6 characters in length i edited my script above

Comment: It gives me ( was unexpected at this time.

Comment: the `if` statements need to be exactly the same as above have you changed them ?

Comment: Whole script is exactly the same as above.

Comment: I made another change try it again

Comment: I'm afraid it's the same. Internet suggests using double %%'s but then when I do that I get "-5 was expected at this time".

Comment: Still does it! Very strange.

Comment: Edited forgot Quotes and changed `set letter`

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! This has certainly given me a start to work on and customise my own way. I can definitely recommend this script to 'reset' profiles and rename/change folder ownership and names in specific folders, indexed by letter.
Thanks.

Comment: good to hear it worked, could you accept my answer above seeing that it has worked thanks.